# PHP array comparison with different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I need to compare values from 2 arrays that are not always the same size, each containing either a login or a logout time.  I need to get the time difference total or time logged in between these values.  Where I am getting caught is the logout result is usually smaller then the login.  I tried the following but it isn't accurate at all.

```
$offset = 0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($login_ary);$i++){
    //unset($time_logged);
    $time_logged = Array();
    while( (int)$login_ary[$i] > (int)$logout_ary[$i] ) {
        $offset++;
    }
    $time_logged['login'] = $login_ary[$i] + $offset;
    $time_logged['logout'] = $logout_ary[$i];

    $calc_ary[] = $time_logged;
}
$time_logged_in = "undefined";
```

End result I need to get either an array with lined up login/logoffs or a calculation of the total time difference between the login time and then logout time.  But I have to exclude logins that don't have an associated logout.

**EDITS**

1) Times inside of the arrays are unix timestamps
2) the arrays aren't static as this is done inside a loop for each user in a result set so the var_dump would look something like the following

login_arr

> Array([0] => '1385402632',[1] => '1385763384',[2] => '1387293992')

logout_arr

> Array([0] => '1387294012')

** MY SOLUTION **

My solution is out of context of the original question which is why I posted it as an edit instead of an answer.  But here is what I did, the simplicity of it makes me feel foolish that I didn't think of it originally.  What I did, is write the session timeout into the logout_ary since the data was going to be unrepresented otherwise, we decided that fudging a time was better then completely avoiding it.  So I took the login time and fudged a logout time and spliced it into the array at the same point.  I still would like to know the true answer to this problem if there is one though.

```
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($login_ary);$i++){
        //unset($time_logged);
        $time_logged = Array();
        if( (int)$login_ary[$i] > (int)$logout_ary[$i] ) {
            array_splice($logout_ary,$i,0,$login_ary[$i]+$session_length);
            $time_logged['login'] = $login_ary[$i];
            $time_logged['logout'] = $logout_ary[$i];
        } else {
            $time_logged['login'] = $login_ary[$i];
            $time_logged['logout'] = $logout_ary[$i];
        }
        $calc_ary[] = $time_logged;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this calculation when fetching the data from the database?

Comment: can you post `var_dump` examples of these arrays so we can get a better idea of their structure? it'll help clarify your question and allow us answer your question better.

Comment: specifically, we would really need to know what format the times are saved in. I would assume a unix timestamp, but it could be anything: `H:i:s`, `h:i:s` or something else. clarification will help.

Comment: I see your update, thanks. in the example `$login_arr` is each element a login timestamp for a different user, or is it a collection of login timestamps for one user? since there is an uneven amount of logins and logouts I assume the latter? if this is the case, is element `$login_arr[0]` and `$logout_arr` the login/logout time for the same user?

Comment: @Darragh yes its for one user and logout isn't present always if they let the session expire

Comment: @Grimnoff thanks for the update, I meant to say 'former' above actually... I had already posted an answer but I realise now it's not based on the correct assumptions based on your last clarification. I'll remove it and amend in the morning.

Comment: @Chris My assumption is that yes it is most likely possible but since each login and logout was its own separate row I couldn't think of a good way to pull it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the comments, I think this might be what you're after comment and I can see if I can help more.

```
<?php

function calcTime($login_ary, $loutout_ary) {

    $login_ary_length = sizeof($login_ary); 
    $logout_ary_length = sizeof($logout_ary);  

    if($login_ary_length != $logout_ary_length) {
        $diff = $login_ary_length - $logout_ary_length;
        //just find the code that suits your format and put it in the function     strtotime()
        $timestamp = strtotime('TODAYS DATE AND TIME');
        //for the amount of diff we add todays date and time to the array so that they are eqal
        for(i=0; i<=$diff; i++) {
        array_push($logout_ary, $timestamp);  
    }

    //I'm going to leave this for you to do.

    return $total_hours; 

    }
}
?>
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: The above is very accurate except when the 2 arrays aren't the same size which is the biggest problem I have...

Comment: @Grimnoff I edited my answer, I didn't complete it all the way as I was working while trying to help.  I did manage to make up a way to solve your issue I think, but maybe I'm on the wrong track.  Essentially I add to the array stack today's date and time  and that will even up the arrays and allow you to do what you want I think... idk might not be the answer you want.

Comment: This is the same way I went about it in the end as well

Comment: @Grimnoff: This would add a lot of complexity to your program, but why not just use a multidimensional array.  For instance you can have one array called log_info In this array you can have another array that signifies users and then another that signifies logout and login times.  When you are filling this multi array you can put values that insist that that user never logged out and then when you are looking for answers you can create a if statement that if their logout time value is this then User still logged in.  This is rather complex, but I think this might be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is stored in the two arrays? Just time variables? How are you to know if say that login_ary[i] is the login time for the log_out[i] time? Also, why not just take the log_out time - the log_in time to get the time differential?

Comment: q1) Yes just time variables
q2) you don't...
q3) have to make sure the log_in time isnt greater then log_out time

Comment: @Grimnoff This seems like it will not work, If each time is not associated with say a user id, then there is no way to match up the login with the logout. This seems counter productive. I would think to make this work would be to have an associated user(login id) associated with a log_in and log_out time. As far as making sure the log_in time isn't greater than log_out time, just use a comparison like: if(log_in[i] < log_out[i]) totalTimeLoggedIn = log_out[i] - log_in[i]